# Getting the average for a certain column based off specific ranges of two other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 columns such as the ones below (but a total of 50,000 values not shown here):

```
Date        Speed        Area        Incidents
1/1/2016     6.5         Maly            L
1/2/2016     7.7         Maly            H
1/3/2016     14          Maly            H
...
1/1/2017     5.5         Reet            M
1/12/2017    9.8         Reet            M
4/8/2017      3          Reet            H
3/12/2017    5.8         Anlow           L
```

I need to try and find the average speed recorded in all of 2017 in the area of Reet where the incidents were M.
So the output for this is supposed to be: **7.65**.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm missing, and so far I have tried using date_range() and set_index with .describe() for my average requirement but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `Date` to datetimes and aggregate year with another columns for sum:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df1 = (df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year.rename('Year'), 'Area','Incidents']).Speed
         .sum() 
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `masks` to select the data you want, and then take the mean:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date' : ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/1/2017', '1/12/2017', '4/8/2017', '3/12/2017'],
        'Speed' : [6.5, 7.7, 14, 5.5, 9.8, 3, 5.8],
        'Area' : ['Maly', 'Maly', 'Maly', 'Reet', 'Reet', 'Reet', 'Anlow'],
        'Incidents':['L', 'H', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'H', 'L']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'date' to datetime and set it as the index
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.index = df['Date']

# Create the mask(s) you want and take the mean of the chosen column
mean_wind_speed = df[(df.index.year==2017) & (df.Area=='Reet') & (df.Incidents == 'M')]['Speed'].mean()
print(mean_wind_speed)
```

outputs:

```
7.65
```

### Edit

one can also use `query`, with a new column for Years:

```py
df['Year'] = df.index.year
mean_wind_speed = df.query('Year == 2017 and Area == "Reet" and Incidents=="M"')['Speed'].mean()
```

Comment: I should have included this, but how would you approach that if you had 50,000 values in your data set to work with?

Comment: I think for 50k values i would do the same, but if speed is an issue, I believe (i didn't check) that the `query()` function is supposed to be faster, so you could replace the `masks` by : `mean_wind_speed = df.query('Year == 2017 and Area == "Reet" and Incidents=="M"')['Speed']`

Comment: I managed to edit the code a little bit and it seems to have worked. Thanks